How can I declare return type as literal object from literal 2 depth recursive array argument?
interface Item {
    a: string
    c?: Array<Item>
}

function g<const T extends item>(p: Array<T>) {
    return {} as {[K in T as K['a']]: any}
}

// type of r is {a0: any, a1: any}
const r1 = g1([
    {
        a: 'a0',
        c: [
            {
                a: 'ac0'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        a: 'a1'
    }
])

We can make the type that consisted with each specific property of array. But actually I want all a property that in last depth, not only depth 1 of a.
interface Item {
    a: string
    c?: Array<Item>
}

function g1<T>(g1:T) {
    return {} // as ..?
}

// I hope that type of r1 is {a0: any, ac0: any, a1: any}
const r1 = g1([
    {
        a: 'a0',
        c: [
            {
                a: 'ac0'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        a: 'a1'
    }
])

I want make the union key type with all a properties of all last child.
Is it possible in TypeScript?
If it is possible, how?

• Please [edit] to use conventional naming; interfaces are conventionally in UpperCamelCase like Item, not item. • Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thank you for help me and fix my convention. TS is amazing!

@jcalz Can you help me one more? If property 'a' of Item is optional, still can do this?
[K in EXIST last child 'c']

"Can you help me one more?" Followup questions belong in new posts, not comments. You can do this, but I don't know what "in EXIST last child" is supposed to mean, and it's out of scope here anyway. I'll write up an answer for the question as asked and if you still have questions you can make a new post.

Given the tree-like definition of Item,
interface Item {
  a: string
  c?: Array<Item>
}

if you want to compute the union of the a properties at all depths of the tree, you'll need to write a recursive type to do it.
Note that such deeply nested recursive types tend to have bizarre edge cases, so it's important that you test fully against your expected types, and be prepared to refactor if some behavior is undesirable.  I'll be using the example as given and not worry about possible edge or corner cases.
Let's write the generic utility type NestedA<T> where T is constrained to Item[], since g1() will accept an Item[] subtype, and the c property is (optionally) an Item[] subtype. Here's one way to do it:
type NestedA<T extends Item[]> = { [I in keyof T]:
  T[I]['a'] | (
    T[I] extends { c: infer C extends Item[] } ? NestedA<C> : never
  )
}[number]

This is a mapped tuple type where I iterates through the numeric-like indices of T. For each element at index I, we calculate T[I]['a'], the indexed access type meaning the type of the property at key "a" of the element at index I of T.  If you have a value t of type T, and a numeric index i of type I, then t[i].a is of type T[I]['a'].  So that gives us the string at the a property.
Then we collect that in a union with the recursive conditional type T[I] extends { c: infer C extends Item[] } ? NestedA<C> : never.  This is saying that we check the that the Ith element of T can be matched against a type with a c property that we infer as a new type parameter C constrained to Item[]. If so, then we evaluate it to the recursive call to NestedA<C>.  Otherwise we stop recursing and evaluate it to the impossible never type.
Finally, we index into that mapped tuple type with number, to get the union of all its properties.

Let's go through an example:
type Tee = [{ a: "x", c: [{ a: "y" }] }, { a: "z" }]

type N = NestedA<Tee>;

That can be expanded to
type N = [
  Tee[0]['a'] | (Tee[0] extends { c: infer C extends Item[] } ? NestedA<C> : never),
  Tee[1]['a'] | (Tee[1] extends { c: infer C extends Item[] } ? NestedA<C> : never),
][number]

The types Tee[0]['a'] and Tee[1]['a'] are "x" and "z", respectively. So now we have
type N = [
  "x" | (Tee[0] extends { c: infer C extends Item[] } ? NestedA<C> : never),
  "z" | (Tee[1] extends { c: infer C extends Item[] } ? NestedA<C> : never),
][number]

For the conditional types, since Tee[0] has a c property of type [{a: "y"}] which does extend Item[], that evaluates to NestedA<[{a: "y"}]>. But since Tee[1] doesn't have a c property, that evaluates to never.  So now we have:
type N = [
  "x" | NestedA<[{ a: "y" }]>,
  "z" | never
][number]

We can do the indexing by number now and get the full union
type N = "x" | NestedA<[{ a: "y" }]> | "z" | never

Now we have to do the recursive call, which looks like
type N = "x" | [
  "y" | never
][number] | "z" | never

And that becomes
type N = "x" | "y" | never | "z" | never

and since never is absorbed by unions, we get
type N = "x" | "y" | "z"

as desired.

Armed with NestedA<T>, we can now write g1():
function g1<const T extends Item[]>(g1: T) {
  return {} as { [K in NestedA<T>]: any }
}

I've made the type parameter T a const type parameter to encourage TypeScript to infer g1 as narrowly as possible, where literal values are inferred as literal types, and array literals are inferred as tuple types.  Otherwise calling g1([{a: "x", c: [{a: "y"}]}]) would end up inferring something like {a: string, c: {a: string}[]}[] for T, which completely loses track of the actual values of a.  With const there we get a type that keeps track of those values.
The return type of g1() is {[K in NestedA<T>]: any}, a mapped type with keys from NestedA<T> and values of type any. It's equivalent to Record<NestedA<T>, any> using the Record<K, V> utility type.
Okay, let's test it:
const r1 = g1([
  {
    a: 'a0',
    c: [
      {
        a: 'ac0'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    a: 'a1'
  }
]);

((r1));
//^? {a0: any, ac0: any, a1: any}

Looks good. The a properties from the input are collected and used as keys for the return type.
Playground link to code
